# svg, path tag does not work on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, path, svg, tags

I am working on a simple map drowning with svg path tag
But it dose not work on fire fox or IE
(the drawing itself does not appear)

hear is a sample of them

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<path id="lineAB" d= "M450.59,294.28l3.64-0.29l5.97,8.44l-5.54,4.18l-4.01-1.03l-5.39,0.07l-0.87,3.16l-4.52,0.22l-1.24-1.69l1.6-5.14L450.59,294.28L450.59,294.28z" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" onclick="alert('Hello')"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Opera, IE and Firefox all work the same for me. I see a blue blob which alerts Hello when you click on it. What's not working for you?

Comment: the drawing itself does not appear

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using commas for the `d` attribute, use spaces instead. Also `stroke-width` has to be a length (e.g. `px`).
This should work:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<path id="lineAB" d= "M450.59 294.28l3.64-0.29l5.97 8.44l-5.54 4.18l-4.01-1.03l-5.39 0.07l-0.87 3.16l-4.52 0.22l-1.24-1.69l1.6-5.14L450.59 294.28L450.59 294.28z" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3px" fill="blue" onclick="alert('Hello')"/>
</svg>
```

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF) for a longer and more accurate explanation :).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what has changed since 2012, but I see no difference between the original code and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13908798/6805143), what makes both of them "work" for me though is adding `viewBox` ([codepen](https://codepen.io/hyvyys/pen/WNdeaLX)):

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="400 200 200 200">
<path id="lineAB" d= "M450.59,294.28l3.64-0.29l5.97,8.44l-5.54,4.18l-4.01-1.03l-5.39,0.07l-0.87,3.16l-4.52,0.22l-1.24-1.69l1.6-5.14L450.59,294.28L450.59,294.28z" stroke-width="3" onclick="alert('Hello')"/>
</svg>


<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="400 200 200 200">
<path id="lineAB" d= "M450.59 294.28l3.64-0.29l5.97 8.44l-5.54 4.18l-4.01-1.03l-5.39 0.07l-0.87 3.16l-4.52 0.22l-1.24-1.69l1.6-5.14L450.59 294.28L450.59 294.28z" stroke-width="3px" onclick="alert('Hello')"/>
</svg>
```

Also, even though using a comma before a command and after the previous command's coordinate breaks it in Firefox, using comma between coordinates themselves works and is perfectly fine as per the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF):

```
coordinate-pair:
    coordinate comma-wsp? coordinate
comma-wsp:
    (wsp+ comma? wsp*) | (comma wsp*)
comma:
    ","
wsp:
    (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)
```