# Why mpld3 examples are not working?

Tags: python, d3.js, matplotlib

Why some graph in the mpld3 gallery or demo are not working ?

For example, here : [Line plot with legend](http://mpld3.github.io/_downloads/mpld3_demo.html#Line-Plots-with-Legend)

I do not see any lines, and it does not work either if I try to reproduce it locally.
Either on Firefox or Safari.
Here is what I see on the previous link:

[image: mpld3]

Note that I can see and reproduce the first 2 graphs of that demo page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like firefox doesn't recognize paths with points separated by commas: [svg, path tag does not work on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661323/svg-path-tag-does-not-work-on-firefox)

mpld3 uses commas rather than spaces throughout. I had previously tested all these plots on a newer version of firefox (I don't have that computer in front of me at the moment), and didn't see this issue. Maybe if you upgrade firefox it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problems in visualizing this plot.
Have you imported numpy like this?

```
import numpy as np
```

if not you will not be able to create the abscissa value using np.linspace..
do you get any message when trying plotting it?

Comment: But it's not working on-line, so it's not a pb from python, but from my browser maybe (which is Firefox).