# The css animation variable in svg <use> tag does not take effect?

Tags: css, svg

- I used svg to draw a port, hope the color and animation of the port can be passed in through variables.
- I use "symbol" to reuse elements, and use css variables to pass parameters. I found that the color var is ok, but the animation var can’t work; if the "symbol" is removed, it’s normal.
- Can anyone guide the reasons for the failure of the animation? How to realize the animation parameters while retaining the "symbol"?
- [codepen](https://codepen.io/lazebird/project/editor/ZeVNGn)

```
... // code snippet
    .led {
      fill: var(--led-color, black);
      animation: color-blink calc(var(--blink-speed, 0)*1s) infinite alternate;
    }
  <use xlink:href="#eport" id="port1" style="--led-color:#2ef055;--blink-speed:0.1;" />
```

- **update the bug report link(it is duplicated): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1238674**

Comment: the snippet works for me on Firefox.

Comment: yes, i used chrome. The graphics are a bit messy in firefox, i will investigate; and which is more in line with the standard? chrome vs. firefox?

Comment: If you've found a Chrome bug, look for it in Chrome's bugtracker and report it if it's not there already.

Comment: thanks. by the way, i just find firefox layout <g id="elight"> width 79px, while its parent <g id="eport" class="global"> width 191px, set elight's width doesn't work. Could this be a bug in firefox? or my code is not rigorous enough?

Comment: g elements don't have a width property. So no that wouldn't be a bug.

Comment: thanks. The graphic display confusion problem in firefox has been clear, and commas cannot be used in the path, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661323/svg-path-tag-does-not-work-on-firefox

Comment: It's animating for me in Chrome (WIndows 10).

Comment: @AHaworth chrome version? mine is 92.0.4515.131. Please pay attention to the 3 examples in the link, where eport_nosymbol.svg is ok, eport.svg is problematic

Comment: Version 92.0.4515.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) Yes, eport.svg animates just once.